# Using a mixin inside a class

Tags: ruby

I would like to make use of a mixin (HTTParty) and access those mixed in methods from inside a class instance. With my current implementation, Ruby is telling me it doesn't know about the method "get":

```
class Recipe
    include HTTParty

    base_uri 'http://www.food2fork.com/api'
    default_params :key => @key
    format :json

  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end

  def search(term)
    get('/search', query: { q: term})['recipes']
  end

    def self.for(term)
        get('/search', query: { q: term})['recipes']
    end
end
```

Scoping is still a big point of confusion for me in Ruby. I am sure this is trivial to the right person. Most examples of a mixin make use of this with a static reference like

```
Recipe.for('term')
```

That's not very OO to me so I want to do it like:

```
recipes = Recipe.new('key')
recipes.search('chocolate')
```

Comment: I'd recommend reading http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html. While we appreciate the difficulty of learning, we expect well thought-out and well-written questions; It's not really germane where you are in the learning curve if you've done sufficient research and your question reflects your effort of researching and trying to solve the problem. We respect the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get` is a class method of *HTTParty*. Rewrite your instance method `search` like this:

```
def search(term)
  self.class.get('/search', query: { q: term})['recipes']
end
```